# Rails Action Mailer: Send email with show page HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am trying to use action mailer to send an email of orders to the websites admin during checkout. The email get sent when the new charges is created but it is not sending the full message. How do I tell the mailer to send the view of the shopping cart show page?

Here is the mailer html. I am pretty sure this @order_items line is incorrect but I am not sure how to tell the mailer to render the HTML from the shopping cart show page? Currently the email sends but it only sends the You have a new order line.
order_email.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You have a new order </h1>
    <p>
     <%= @order_items %> <br>
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is my shopping cart show page the shopping_cart partial lists all of the order_items. 
cart/show.html.erb:

```
<div class="shopping-cart">
     <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
     <h4 class="text-right">Subtotal: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.subtotal %></span></h4>
     <h4 class="text-right">Shipping: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.shipping %></span></h4>
      <h4 class="text-right">Order Total: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.total %></span></h4>

    <%= link_to 'Checkout', new_charge_path %>>
    </div>
```

Charges controller 
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    def new

```
end

def create
  # Amount in cents
   @amount = (current_order.total * 100).to_i
   OrderMailer.order_email(@order_items).deliver_now


  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      =>  @amount,
    :description => 'Order',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path

end
```

end

Here is my mailer:

```
class OrderMailer < ApplicationMailer
   add_template_helper(OrderItemsHelper)

  default from: "xxxx@gmail.com"

  def order_email(order_items)
     @order_items = order_items
       mail(to: "xxx@gmail.com", subject: "New Order")
  end
end
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
OrderMailer#order_email: processed outbound mail in 46.1ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 138ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial order_mailer/_shopping_cart, application_mailer/_shopping_cart with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"
  * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views"
):
    1: 
    2: <div class="shopping-cart">
    3: 
    4:   <%= render "shopping_cart" %>
    5:  <h4 class="text-right">Subtotal: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.subtotal %></span></h4>
    6:  <h4 class="text-right">Shipping: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.shipping %></span></h4>
    7:   <h4 class="text-right">Order Total: <span style="color: green"><%= number_to_currency current_order.total %></span></h4>
  app/views/carts/show.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_carts_show_html_erb__237194399509057886_70276459395980'
  app/views/order_mailer/order_email.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_order_mailer_order_email_html_erb___3173067988541617898_70276461477720'
  app/mailers/order_mailer.rb:11:in `order_email'
  app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:10:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (32.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (140.8ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails 5, I think you should be able to use your controller's renderer, using the `#{controller_name}Controller.renderer.render` method.

Here is another way you could do this:

With your current setup,

```
    <h1>You have a new order </h1>
    <%= render(template: 'carts/show', locals: {pass in your local variables, if any, here}) %>
```

Notice I removed the html wrappers, because most times, those are defined already within the layout template.

Let me know if that works

Comment: I tried  <%= render(template: 'carts/show') %> but I am getting an error that says Missing partial order_mailer/_shopping_cart my shopping cart show page does have a _shopping_cart partial. Is there something I should add to the code so it will find the partial too?

Comment: Yeah, most times it's always better to be explicit in your render methods. You should be able to fix that by changing from `<%= render "shopping_cart" %>` to `<%= render "carts/shopping_cart" %>`

Comment: Upvote and accept the answer if it does solve the problem, though.

Comment: so i would I need to render both the carts/show page and the carts/_shopping_cart partial? I am still getting a missing partial error.

Comment: Unless there are some other partials which you have to explicitly add, I don't believe you should still be getting the errors you've mentioned. BTW, could you add the specific errors you're getting.

Comment: I have edited the post to show the error I have been getting. It seems like it is rendering the carts show view all right but then it gets stuck at the _shopping_cart partial that is in the show view.

Comment: Yeah, I said in your carts/show.html.erb, you should change the second line to `<%= render "carts/shopping_cart" %>`